# enabeling comet in glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, comet

i am getting following error

```
#|2010-10-31T19:13:38.127+0530|SEVERE|glassfish|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|StandardWrapperValve[Grizzly Cometd Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Grizzly Cometd Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Make sure you have enabled Comet or make sure the Thread invoking that method is the same a the request Thread.
 at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometContext.addCometHandler(CometContext.java:263)
 at com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet.doPost(CometdServlet.java:159)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.preInvoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:462)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:139)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:187)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:242)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:633)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:570)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:827)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:152)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(GlassfishProtocolChain.java:71)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:103)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:89)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:67)
 at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:56)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.processTask(WorkerThreadImpl.java:325)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:184)
|#]

[#|2010-10-31T19:14:51.754+0530|SEVERE|glassfish|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|StandardWrapperValve[Grizzly Cometd Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Grizzly Cometd Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Make sure you have enabled Comet or make sure the Thread invoking that method is the same a the request Thread.
 at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometContext.addCometHandler(CometContext.java:263)
 at com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet.doPost(CometdServlet.java:159)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.preInvoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:462)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:139)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:187)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:242)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:633)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:570)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:827)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:152)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(GlassfishProtocolChain.java:71)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:103)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:89)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:67)
 at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:56)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.processTask(WorkerThreadImpl.java:325)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:184)
|#]
```

Am using following in domain.xml

```
<http-listener default-virtual-server="server" server-name="" address="0.0.0.0" port="%%%HTTP_PORT%%%" id="http-listener-1">
   <!-- added by akshay -->
   <property name="cometSupport" value="true"/>
   <!-- done -->
  </http-listener>
        <http-listener default-virtual-server="server" enabled="false" security-enabled="true" server-name="" address="0.0.0.0" port="%%%HTTP_SSL_PORT%%%" id="http-listener-2">
          <ssl ssl3-enabled="false" cert-nickname="s1as" />
    <!-- added by akshay -->
   <property name="cometSupport" value="true"/>
   <!-- done -->
        </http-listener>
        <http-listener default-virtual-server="__asadmin" server-name="" address="0.0.0.0" port="%%%ADMIN_PORT%%%" id="admin-listener">
   <!-- added by akshay -->
   <property name="cometSupport" value="true"/>
   <!-- done -->
  </http-listener>
```

Answer (score 8):

Enabling Comet Support in Web Admin Console

1. Start GlassFish Server, navigate to Web Admin Console (default:
   localhost:4848/) in browser.
2. At "Common Task" pan on left hand side, select "Configuration" –>
   "Network Config" –> "Network Listeners" –> "http-listener-1"
3. At "Edit Network Listener", select tab "HTTP".
4. Under tab "HTTP", select the checkbox of "Comet Support"
5. Click "Save" button (at top of frame)

Done!

Comment: For those using Glassfish 4.0 or above, the admin console asks to set a valid post size, even when you don't edit this value (bug of GUI?). The workaround is enabling comet via console, as the solution of @Pascal Thivent and comments sets

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how the `domain.xml` is supposed to be structured in GF 3.x but to enable comet support, you are supposed to use the following command:

> #### [Enabling Comet](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1752/ghhaw?l=en&a=view)
>
> Before running a Comet-enabled
>   application, you need to enable Comet
>   in the HTTP listener for your
>   application by setting a special
>   attribute in the associated protocol
>   configuration. The following example
>   shows the asadmin set command that
>   adds this attribute:
>
> ```
> asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-1.http.comet-support-enabled="true"
> ```
>
> Substitute the name of the protocol
>   for `http-1`.

I would try that with a clean `domain.xml` (i.e. non manually edited).

#### References

- GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Application Development Guide

  - [Using Comet](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1752/ggrgt?l=en&a=view)

Comment: I'm have problem to enable comet in glassfish 3 too. I tried this: `asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-1.http.comet-support-enabled="true"` but didn't work, what do they mean by: `"Substitute the name of the protocol for http-1"`? i tried `asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.bayeux.http.comet-support-enabled="true"` but didn't work either, i get this error: `No configuration found for server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-1.http`

Comment: For Glassfish 3.1.2.2 try `set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.comet-support-enabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers.

I will ask you you to check if comet jar you are using to compile your application corresponds comet implementation in glassfish.

For example I've made 2 mistakes:

1. I included comet jar into war file (it should be used only to
   compile project)
2. I used wrong (outdated) version of comet
       implementation('com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-comet:1.9.59') to compile
       project for GF-4.0.

Problem was fixed by updating library to: 
'org.glassfish.main.grizzly:glassfish-grizzly-extra-all:4.0'